# I need my data to be displayed from 2016 till today on monthly basis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

I have a table Product and i want to know about the Product count on monthly basis from 2016 till now.

```
Example:
January     15    2016
February    25    2016
March       05    2016
April       12    2016
```

I'm using this Oracle Query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DATE, 'Month') As "Month",
       login_date, 
       Count(TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DATE, 'Month')) 
from Product 
group by TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DATE, 'Month')"
```

But It shows Error of not a group by expression.

Need suggestions in this matter.

Comment: If you want to count the number of rows per month, you need to use `count(*)` don't include the column you group by in an aggregate function. That doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

It's proper to use EXTRACT function with nested SQL :

```
SELECT Year, Month, count(1) countOfProd 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT extract( month from LOGIN_DATE ) Month,
          extract( year  from LOGIN_DATE ) Year              
     FROM Product
  )  
 GROUP BY Year, Month
 ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be2140/1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a column in your `SELECT` statement that is neither aggregated nor included in the `GROUP BY` clause (`login_date`):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DATE, 'Month') As "Month",
       login_date, 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
       Count(TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DATE, 'Month')) 
  from Product 
 group by TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DATE, 'Month')
```

I suspect you want something more like the following (keeping in mind that `COUNT(*)` is more intuitive than `Count(TO_CHAR(LOGIN_DATE, 'Month'))` - and also you won't have to worry about cases where `login_date` is NULL):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(login_date, 'Month YYYY'), COUNT(*)
  FROM product 
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(login_date, 'Month YYYY');
```

Note that I also included the year in the date mask for `TO_CHAR()` - otherwise you run the risk of two months' (say, January 2016 and January 2017) counts getting aggregated together. Personally I would use `TRUNC(login_date, 'MONTH')` (this will return the first of the month) and leave the formatting to the client:

```
SELECT TRUNC(login_date, 'MONTH'), COUNT(*)
  FROM product 
 GROUP BY TRUNC(login_date, 'MONTH');
```

Hope this helps.